# Print image of any size to full Letter page in coldfusion

Tags: image, coldfusion, image-resizing

After customizing images (add text to images), image is converted to pdf using cfdocument to print the image but image is not stretched to full size page. Image sizes are not always the same and can range from 300x400 to 3300x2745

Following code works only if dimensions are above 800x600 but not below. Images below 800x600 dimensions just display the image at the center of the print preview with a lot of white space around it (does not stretch). I'm stuck and any suggestions or help is appreciated.

```
<cfoutput>
<!--- <cfdocument format="pdf" orientation="landscape">--->
<cfdocument format ="pdf" pageHeight="11" Pagewidth="8.5" pagetype="custom" margintop="0.001" marginright="0.001" marginleft="0.001" marginbottom="0.001" orientation="landscape">
<img src="images/toy.jpg">

</cfdocument>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I had no idea until I did a google search on `coldfusion image functions`.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. I tried ImageResize, ImageScaletoFit with no much luck. I'm going to try and see if I could somehow figure out the dimensions of full page after converting to PDF and do some calculations. Not sure if it helps but will give it a try. I not only have to resize image but also convert to PDF.

Comment: (Update) What was the actual result when you tried ImageResize? You only said you had "no..luck".  I'd imagine you just need the correct image dimensions and resize it either with ImageResize or using CSS.  Keep in mind the images themselves may contain some sort of white space border that make it appear as if the image doesn't expand to the full page. Example https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=36f4c7cf-48f4-4426-a112-bfe470a43fb4/695e3d76-fc02-4216-935b-c4ebb64eb216/024a31c7-66dd-43a6-bf86-97f94ab2dc45.cfm

Comment: CFDocument renders HTML. Have you tried adding "width" and "height" attributes to the IMG tag?  (This is how I currently do it using ColdFusion and WKHTMLTOPDF.)

Comment: I apologize for asking question incorrectly. Using imageResize or css in html shows the pdf correctly with margin settings. Without marking settings, it was creating 2 pages. The issue is when I issue print command, print preview always have some kind of margin and scale % is always set to "set to printable area" and shows margin in the preview. I can manually change it to actual size to make it work the way I wanted (full print screen)? Can I somehow set it so it keeps the margin settings the way I configured?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you considered using WKHTMLTOPDF? (I've been using it since CF8.)  If so, you could use newer HTML5 & CSS3. (CFDocument hasn't been updated in a very long time.)  I recommend using a valid HTML (a single IMG tag isn't valid HTML) and set HTML BODY size, margins and IMG inline style (width:100%; height:auto;... I use "object-fit:contain;" with WKHTMLTOPDF.)

Comment: Thank You all for your response. Not sure why but it wasn't working for us. Unfortunately, I cannot share the image. As of now, we only wanted to fix 1 image and so we made it 800x600 and worked perfectly with SOS solution.